# bash: powershell: command not found

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, ssh, window, remote-access

For a node project I will have to work on a remote server and for that I will use filzilla for file transfer and ssh for console.

I use Visual Studio Code, I installed a **remote ssh** extension,
I did the hostname and user configurations as well as secretkey,
because before that I had another error **The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe** ,
which I finally solved but now after I start ssh and log in with the password in cmd from Visual Studio Code, I get this error bash: **powershell: command not found**.

I tried one day to search the internet for that error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting

I've talked to people who have more experience but within the time limit my advice could be, but I still couldn't solve the error, either it's something from windows or ssh or I don't know.
You are the first time I try to do this in general I used heroku or aws that had some facilities.

[image]

Comment: Id' say, start small to find the error. Can you start wsl? Can you start pwsh in that wsl instance? Can you run that script in the wsl instance?

Comment: I using Windows, I can use wsl instance

Answer (score 4):

I changed host machine in the settings JSON file windows to linux

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing more information. Could you share the JSON file you changed for the OP to gain a better understanding of the solution.

Comment: To find the settings JSON file: [Settings file locations § Visual Studio Code User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). Modify the host type in the `remote.SSH.remotePlatform` property.

Comment: Or you can change the host type in GUI: open **Preferences** > [**Settings**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), and then search `remote.SSH.remotePlatform` .

Answer (score 2):

When you got the option to Select Linux, Windows or Mac did you make sure that you know exactly the type of server you are connecting to. Bcs if you choose the wrong one this error gets thrown.

Comment: For now, if you connected to an **A** type host previously, and now you want to connect to the same address (or domain) but **B** type host, VS Code will fail and won't let you change the host type directly, so users have to edit the saved setting by themselves.